# How do you change the "read more" tag in posts on a category by category basis

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a category called "Blog", by default the read more tag is configured to say "continue reading".

I have another category called "events". How do I change the read more tag for posts linked to this category to say "view event"?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information? For example which blogging platform.

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry. I am using wordpress